# Undefined property: WP_Post_Type::$ID

Tags: plugins, php, post-type

Using the Query Monitor Plugin - I'm getting this Error **Undefined property: WP_Post_Type::$ID** for this function:

```
public function add_form_modal() {
    $button_group = get_post_meta( get_queried_object()->ID, 'button_group', true );

    if ( empty( $button_group ) || ! is_array( $button_group ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    if ( 'form' !== $button_group['button_type'] ) {
        return '';
    }

    $form_id = $button_group['button_link'];
    ?>
    <div class="lsx-modal modal fade" id="cf-modal-<?php echo esc_attr( $form_id ); ?>" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo esc_html( $button_group['button_text'] ); ?></h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <?php echo do_shortcode( '[caldera_form id="' . $form_id . '"]' ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

If someone can please guide me through the cause be of this issue so I can understand and fix it - Would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the `get_queried_object()->ID` to `get_queried_object_id()`.

All the get queried object may not have a property name `$ID`. So this `get_queried_object_id` gives the `$queried_object_id` property value, which gets set on instantiation of `WP_Query` class. If the `$queried_object_id` isn't set then it'll give you `0`.

Comment: You should also check `is_singular()` first. Otherwise if you're viewing a category/taxonomy archive then it will use the category ID. If you have a post with the same ID as a category then you could load an unexpected value with `get_post_meta()`.